# VBA Microsoft Access Check boxes not filtering data

Tags: ms-access, vba

On Form 002_Criteria, I have a checkbox. Currently it does nothing, and I would like for these check boxes to display related data under that field  that is checked in a List Box on Form 003_Species. The list box is rowsource is a query know as qSciName. It currently has all the scientific name showing in the list box. The query has multiple tables such as PlantSpecies with field names like PlantSpeciesID, SciName, ComName and another table know as Criteria has the SciName criteria.

I tried the following coding and it did not filter my the results in the list box. I also tried listing the fields in the query and using the criteria to point the check box. When I did this and the more fields I add, it would subtract the Scientific Names until nothing displayed. What can you do to get my code to work properly?

Thank you for help :)

```
Private Sub Refilter()

    Dim strFilterString As String

    'BUILD THE FILTER STRING:
    If Forms("002_Criteria").CKNFixer = True Then
        strFilterString = strFilterString & " OR NFixer ='True'"
    End If

    If Forms("002_Criteria").CkSun = True Then
        strFilterString = strFilterString & " OR TolerantSun ='True'"
    End If

    If Forms("002_Criteria").CKShade = True Then
        strFilterString = strFilterString & " OR TolerantShade ='True'"
    End If

    If Forms("002_Criteria").CKWind = True Then
        strFilterString = strFilterString & " OR TolerantWind ='True'"
    End If

    If Forms("002_Criteria").CkSalt = True Then
        strFilterString = strFilterString & " OR TolerantSalt ='True'"
    End If

    If Forms("002_Criteria").CkPollinator = True Then
        strFilterString = strFilterString & " OR Pollinator ='True'"
    End If

    If Forms("002_Criteria").CkNative = True Then
        strFilterString = strFilterString & " OR Native ='True'"
    End If

    If Forms("002_Criteria").CKIntroduce = True Then
        strFilterString = strFilterString & " OR introduce ='True'"
    End If

    'REMOVE LEADING " OR " ON FILTER STRING:
    If strFilterString <> "" Then strFilterString = Mid(strFilterString, 5)

    'APPLY FILTER STRING TO 003_Species:
    If strFilterString <> "" Then
        Forms("003_Species").ListSciName.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM [qSciName] WHERE " & strFilterString
    Else
        Forms("003_Species").ListSciName.RowSource = "qSciName"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Fields like `TolerantShade` are a string or Yes/No? If Yes/No, then remove single quotes.

Comment: Sergey S. They are Yes/No, I did remove the single and vba still did nothing with filtering the list box.

Comment: Does your final query, which you set to the `RowSource` property work well, if you run it by hand, for example by creating a new query object?

Comment: Are you sure about `OR`? Maybe you need to use `AND` instead?

Comment: I will try replace or with and, I dont think it will make a difference at all as should have been doing something by now.